# Eclipse (GWT) doesn't run google webapplication project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, plugins

I've installed Eclipse(Indigo) and Java jdk1.7.0_01. I also installed the google appengine plugin with GWT SDK 2.4.0 and App Engine SDK 1.5.5

included.
The Java jdk1.7.0_01 is checked in the Eclipse preferences, installed JRE's.
When I create a new google webapplication as a project in Eclipse with an example code, everything appears to be running normally and the google

webapplication is being created as a project in Eclipse.
But when I try to run the project, the console comes up with the following anouncement:

**Loading modules**

**com.demo.Demo**

**[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/demo/Demo.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?**

**[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method**

When I try to ignore this error by unchecking this error in google settings. When I run the program and when I execute the demo, I get this error message:

```
nov 14, 2011 10:25:53 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
nov 14, 2011 10:25:53 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Oswin\workspace2\demo\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
nov 14, 2011 10:25:53 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Oswin\workspace2\demo\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
nov 14, 2011 11:25:55 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
nov 14, 2011 10:26:11 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /demo/greet
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 17 in method com.googleapp.demo.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; at offset 4
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: JDKs required for use of 1.5.5 app engine sdk is 1.5 or 1.6 (you have 1.7).  Try installing 1.6.  I'm not putting this as an answer because I'm not positive it addresses your issues...just a guess... http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing.html

Comment: if the jdk isn't the problem, could you post a screenshot of your project structure? and the used run configuration, just in case?

Comment: Thanks for the answering, I give it a try and try out Java 1.6 . It might be possible!

Comment: Tried Java 1.6 on Eclipse. Had no differents. I'll try to post a screenshot to show how things look like.

Comment: When I try to ignore this error by unchecking this error in google settings. When I run the program and when I execute the demo, I get this error message:

Comment: days have passed and nobody knows the answer. Can please someone give me the answer in how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this issue by adding `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to the JVM arguments in `Project Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> [your project's GWT config] -> Arguments -> VM Arguments`. I'm not sure why it works, and that's why I'm searching the internet right now -- trying to find the "why" for my "what." :)

Comment: It works, but whay? Could you please enlighten me, google search doesn't return anything by "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"

Comment: The best I can tell you is to see what Oracle said on the matter [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html). I am not sure what the difference is, but it definitely fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Colleagues on Win 7 64bit and Mac (Intel) didn't have this problem with the same code project. Are we all here Linux users? (Debian testing AMD64 for me)

Comment: Reproduced on Windows 7 x64 on AMD 5000+, Eclipse 3.7.2, Java 1.7.0 32-bit. UseSplitVerifier  helped.